# Chrome: сохранение правок в HTML для чужих сайтов

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Есть ли на Chrome какое-нибудь расширение, способное запомнить те изменения, которые я через devTools внесу. А потом при рендере сайта, подменять указанные мной блоки кода. Хочу вклинить изменения между загрузкой и отображением.

Нужна некая альтернатива AddBlock, но для знающих html / CSS / js. Больше даже CSS. Элементарные действия нужны: display поменять, float и т.п. На некоторых сайтах позиционирование выполнено крайне неудобно и порой незначительных изменений не хватает, чтобы страница начала выглядеть в разы информативнее.

Comment: Вас интересует готовое расширение или как такое разработать?

Comment: Готовое решение.

Answer (score 2):

Для CSS есть [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=ru). Можно создавать свои стили или воспользоваться готовыми, например с https://userstyles.org/

Для JS есть [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=ru) и другие подобные (их много). Также есть множество готовых **USERSCRIPT**'ов (расширение файлов user.js) на Гитхаб и других сайтах. Однако в хроме предусмотрена возможность подключать файлы user.js и без расширения на вкладке расширений, но Tampermonkey позволяют удобнее ими управлять, обновлять и править их. **Из неизвестных источников скрипты стоит подключать с осторожностью!**

Аналогичные расширения есть и для Firefox и других браузеров.